# Onclick event deletes past input fields in table

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="scripts/randomletter.js"></script>
    <h2>NomiCoseCittàAnimali</h2>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Clicca qui sotto per generare una lettera casuale</div>
    <div><button onclick="ranlet()"></button></div>
    <div>
        <table id="gametable">
            <tr>
                <th>Nomi</th>
                <th>Cose</th>
                <th>Città</th>
                <th>Animali</th>
                <th>Punteggio</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div><button onclick="gentable()">Click here to generate a new row</button></div>
</body>


</html>
```

And here my JS

```
function ranlet() {
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var x = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 1000) % 25)

    alert ("La lettera trovata è " +characters[x]);
}

function gentable() {
    document.getElementById('gametable').innerHTML +=
    "<tr>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"range\" min=0 max=4 step=0.5></td>"+
    "</tr>";
}
```

**Click here to generate a new row** appends the table innerHTML with a new row with new elements.
This happens everytime I click on it, the problem is that everytime I click on it deletes precedent input fields, it creates correctly new rows but it completely deletes any value saved.

Is there a way when executing gentable() to keep values from precedents input fields without deleting them?

Answer (score 0):

By using `document.getElementById('gametable').innerHTML` that way, you are resetting your entire table's html and is creating several `<tbody>` tags in the process (deleting whatever was there before), that's not the way.

What you should do is *append* a new element (row) to the table every time the button is pressed.

Also, this type of DOM manipulation would be so much easier using something like jQuery.

```js
function ranlet() {
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var x = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 1000) % 25)

    alert ("La lettera trovata è " +characters[x]);
    
}

function gentable() {
    document.getElementById('gametable').innerHTML +=
    "<tr>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"range\" min=0 max=4 step=0.5></td>"+
    "</tr>";
}



function appendRow() {
    const newRow = document.createElement('tr')
    let td, input;
    
    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
      td = document.createElement('td')
      input = document.createElement('input')
      input.setAttribute('type','text')
      td.appendChild(input)
      newRow.appendChild(td)
    }
    
    
    td = document.createElement('td')
    input = document.createElement('input')
    input.setAttribute('type','range')
    input.setAttribute('min',0)
    input.setAttribute('max',4)
    input.setAttribute('step',0.5)
    td.appendChild(input)
    newRow.appendChild(td)
    
    document.getElementById('gametable').appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="scripts/randomletter.js"></script>
    <h2>NomiCoseCittàAnimali</h2>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Clicca qui sotto per generare una lettera casuale</div>
    <div><button onclick="ranlet()"></button></div>
    <div>
        <table id="gametable">
            <tr>
                <th>Nomi</th>
                <th>Cose</th>
                <th>Città</th>
                <th>Animali</th>
                <th>Punteggio</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
 
    <button onclick="appendRow()">Click here to generate a new row</button>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the code `document.getElementById('gametable').innerHTML`, it causes the content of the DOM element to be parsed and rebuilt, which is what causes your input to be lost. Instead, you should use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Descriptions from the MDN:

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> Setting the value of innerHTML removes all of the element's descendants and replaces them with nodes constructed by parsing the HTML given in the string htmlString.

[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

> The insertAdjacentHTML() method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element.

```js
function ranlet() {
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var x = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 1000) % 25)

    alert ("La lettera trovata è " +characters[x]);
}

function gentable() {
    document.getElementById('gametable').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',( 
    "<tr>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"+
    "<td><input type=\"range\" min=0 max=4 step=0.5></td>"+
    "</tr>"                                         
                                                           ));
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Clicca qui sotto per generare una lettera casuale</div>
    <div><button onclick="ranlet()"></button></div>
    <div>
        <table id="gametable">
            <tr>
                <th>Nomi</th>
                <th>Cose</th>
                <th>Città</th>
                <th>Animali</th>
                <th>Punteggio</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div><button onclick="gentable()">Click here to generate a new row</button></div>
</body>
```